# iOS : how to preserve webview while dismissing a viewcontroller

Tags: ios, cordova-plugins

I have a Cordova application with two view controllers.

MainViewController has HTML Pages A,B & C (All loaded via the webview)

User launches SecondViewController(which has webview) from Page A (via cordova plugin) and launches an online form.

Goes back to Page A(By dismissing SecondViewController) and Moves to Page B and launches the SecondViewController again.

I want to bring up the webview(in SecondViewController) in the same state where user has left it.

Answer (score 0):

I Found one solution for this.

Just add View of Second View controller(having web view)  as sub view of Main View Controller.

Hide and Show view of Second View Controller..

Hope this helps some one.